# Creating a WSClient with Java using PlayWS - Materializer null

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka-stream

Basically, I'm trying to create a custom WSClient in my SBT application using Java. Since I don't want any injection dependencies I'm using the method that is shown in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS#using-wsclient). To create the custom WSClient it needs an Akka.stream.Materializer object but since it's abstract I cannot create a Materializer object.

```
private Materializer materializer;


private WSClient wsClient() throws IOException {

    scala.Option<String> noneString = scala.None$.empty();
    WSClientConfig wsClientConfig = new WSClientConfig(
            Duration.apply(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // connectionTimeout
            Duration.apply(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // idleTimeout
            Duration.apply(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // requestTimeout
            true, // followRedirects
            true, // useProxyProperties
            noneString, // userAgent
            true, // compressionEnabled / enforced
            SSLConfigFactory.defaultConfig());

    AhcWSClientConfig clientConfig = AhcWSClientConfigFactory.forClientConfig(wsClientConfig);

    // Add underlying asynchttpclient options to WSClient
    AhcConfigBuilder builder = new AhcConfigBuilder(clientConfig);
    DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder ahcBuilder = builder.configure();
    AsyncHttpClientConfig.AdditionalChannelInitializer logging = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.AdditionalChannelInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(io.netty.channel.Channel channel) throws Exception {

        }
    };
    ahcBuilder.setHttpAdditionalChannelInitializer(logging);
    // #ws-custom-client

   
    WSClient customWSClient = new play.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient(ahcBuilder.build(), materializer);
    // #ws-client

    // #ws-close-client
    customWSClient.close();
    return customWSClient;
}
```

**Note - I don't want to use Dependency Injection**

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to avoid dependency injection? This is how the framework works now. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Because i'm developing an api that's suppose to run on the framework. So if i create a separate play app then i will running a play app inside a play app.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Akka Streams docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/stream/stream-quickstart.html):

```
akka.actor.ActorSystem system = play.libs.Akka.system();
akka.stream.Materializer materializer = akka.stream.ActorMaterializer.create(system);
```

Keep in mind that `play.libs.Akka.system()` is deprecated and will be remove in the future.

Comment: It gives an error like this.

java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application. Also it says that Akka.system is depreicated.

Comment: Yep. As I said at the answer, `play.libs.Akka.system()` was deprecated in favor of using DI (which you don't want to use). About the exception, how are you running the code? Is it a Play application or isolated?

Comment: It is an isolated one.

Comment: So you need to create your own `ActorSystem` too. See [ActorSystem.create](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.8/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#create--) methods.